# Error trying to diff '[object Object]' Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, ngfor

Estoy intentando en mi aplicación hacer una llamada *GET* a la *API* y una vez hecha, hacer un `ngFor` para traer los nombres de unos servicios. La llamada al *GET* la hace correctamente, el problema es con el `ngFor` que me da el siguiente error:

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]' Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

Mi service.ts

```
export class TikService {

  service: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   
    this.getServices();
   
   }


   private getServices (){
    const getTypeUrl = environment.servicesURL;

    this.http.get(getTypeUrl)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.service = data as string[];
      console.log(data);

    });
   }
```

Mi component.ts

```
import { TikService } from 'ruta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service',
  templateUrl: 'template',
  styleUrls: ['estilos']
})
export class SelectServiceComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
 
    private router: Router,
    public tikService: TikService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  } 
}
```

Mi html

```
<ul class="s_list">

    <li *ngFor="let servicio of tikService.service">
      <button class="btn">{{ servicio.name }}</button>
 </li>
```

Array que devuelve:

```
data: Array(1)
0: Array(4)
0: {createdAt: '2020-06-09T13:37:14', createdBy: 1, active: true, id: 1, name: 'Servicio1', …}
1: {createdAt: '2020-06-11T12:22:10', createdBy: 4, updatedAt: '2020-07-08T16:50:32', name: 'Servicio2', active: true, …}
2: {createdAt: '2020-06-11T12:23:04', createdBy: 4, updatedAt: '2020-07-08T16:50:41', name: 'Servicio3', active: true, …}
3: {createdAt: '2020-06-23T09:59:49', createdBy: 4, updatedAt: '2020-07-08T16:49:38', name: 'Servicio4', active: true, …}
length: 4
```

¿Cuál es el problema que hace que no me funcione el ngFor?

Comment: estas intentando iterar un objeto representado en el `tikService.service,`, el ngFor solo funciona en arrays, seria bueno que recorrieras el service[] con un `for of`, pero depende de la respuesta de tu api la cual nos ayudara mucho si la compartes para conocer la estructura.

Comment: Hola Artes, discúlpame soy bastante novata con estas cosas. ¿A qué te refieres con compartir la estructura? Efectivamente cuando llamo a la API me devuelve un array. Por oro lado, ¿de qué modo puedo recorrer el services con un "for of". Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ok no te preocupes, me refiero a si puedes compartir ese array que te devuelve la API, y qué quieres obtener de ahí?, dependiendo de eso se podrá formular una logica.

Comment: Hola Artes, he compartido el array en la entrada inicial. Es un array que devuelve 4 elementos. Yo necesito sacar el "name" por eso en el html después de hacer el ngFor en el <li> llamo al servicio.name. Gracias.

Comment: ok por lo que veo tu array esta construido asi `[0 [ 0:{'primer objeto}, 1: {segundo objeto}, etc] ]`, por lo cual en tu ngfor tendrias que acceder al elemento `[0]`  del array por lo cual tu `ngFor` podria quedar así  `<li *ngFor="let servicio of array[0]"><button class="btn">{{ servicio.name }}</button></li> ` intentalo. Si no habra que cambar un poco la lógica.

Comment: No, no me deja ponerlo así. Me dice que la propiedad "array" no existe en el componente

Comment: cuando puse array, me referia a tu array es decir `*ngFor="let servicio of tikService[0]"` suponiendo que `tikService` es tu array

Comment: funciona haciendo esto pero desde la petición get en el data[0]. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te indican en los comentarios, el problema es que los datos tienen el formato `{ data: [[servicio1], [servicio2], [...], [servicion]] }`. Observando tu código, sin embargo, si me lo permites, me gustaría hacerte varias sugerencias.

1. En servicios que hacen llamadas a la API es preferible devolver el observable, y hacer la subscripción en el propio componente. De esta manera sólo haces las llamadas cuando las necesitas.
2. Puedes usar el pipe `async` para que Angular gestione las subscripciones automáticamente por ti en las plantillas de los componentes (*templates*) ([enlace](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)).
3. Si necesitas formatear el resultado de un observable, puedes transformar los datos haciendo uso de `pipe` y `map` ([enlace](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map)).

Así quedaría tu código aplicando todo esto:

```
export class TikService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private getServices(): Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.http.get(environment.servicesURL)
      .pipe(map(data => data[0]));
  }
```

```html
<ul class="s_list">
  <li *ngFor="let servicio of servicios$ | async">
    <button class="btn">{{ servicio.name }}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
import { TikService } from 'ruta';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service',
  templateUrl: 'template',
  styleUrls: ['estilos']
})
export class SelectServiceComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    public tikService: TikService
  ) {}
  
  servicios$!: Observable<Array<any>>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.services = this.tikService.getServices();
  }

}
```